# After windows update getting this error AttributeError: olEmbeddeditem

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, win32com

I have windows 10 environment with Python 2.7, win32com package 219 is installed.

I was able to run below code which runs a macro in excel and generate a pie chart that will get attached(also get embedded in email body) to email and sent.
This program was working fine, earlier, however after some windows update, the same is giving AttributeError: olEmbeddeditem, i have imported win32com.client and its constant.

Want the embedded image in the email body, so replacing olEmbeddeditem with olByValue, etc. will not help, i think, though i have tried, which also didn't worked.

I have also done reinstallation of win32com package of python, however problem persist.

Earlier working code does not included "from win32com.client import constants", however since it was not working, have thought of adding this line, but this too didn't helped.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import sys
import os
import win32com.client
import codecs
from win32com.client import constants

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("iso-8859-1")(sys.stdout, 'xmlcharrefreplace')
outlook =     win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
all_inbox = inbox.Items
folders = inbox.Folders

olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") 
ExcelWorkBook =     xlApp.Workbooks.Open('C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\data.xlsm') 
xlSheet1 = ExcelWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1") 
xlApp.Application.Run("data.xlsm!Macro1")
chart1 = xlSheet1.ChartObjects(1) 
chart1.Chart.Export("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\photo.gif", "GIF", False)
xlApp.Workbooks(1).Close(SaveChanges=0)
xlApp.Application.Quit()
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "Presentation of Automation"
attachment = newMail.Attachments.Add("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\photo.gif", win32com.client.constants.olEmbeddeditem, 0, "photo")
imageCid = "photo.gif"
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid)
newMail.HTMLBody = "<body>Dear Sir,Madam,<br>Please find the requested details.<br><br><p><img src=\"cid:{0}\"></body>".format(imageCid)
newMail.To = x
attachment1 = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\photo.gif"
newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
newMail.Send()
os.remove("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\photo.gif")
msg.UnRead = False
```

Comment: please show the detailed exception you get, including line number (which you should mark in your code just to be clear)

Comment: @Schollii, please find the exception i was getting.
'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\abc.py", line 21, in <module>
    x = msg.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'PrimarySmtpAddress'
'

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the issue was not a Windows update as suspected, however it was because of a group email in the Inbox which was giving the error. After deleting that group mail or moving to different folder than Inbox the issue got resolved. Still not sure about the reason why it was giving the error and what is the way out going forward to ensure that such emails does not end up into a traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this attribute error is because your COM-server has shifted from late-binding (dynamic) to early binding (static).

Delete the gen_py folder in Temp which will revert the Dispatch to dynamic from static and your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
attachment = newMail.Attachments.Add("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\photo.gif", win32com.client.constants.olEmbeddeditem, 0, "photo")
```

you can do

```
attachment = newMail.Attachments.Add("C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\photo.gif", 0x5, 0, "photo")
```